# Jquery not removing variable's Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chess

I'm making a chess website for practice and am trying to assign a variable to an element by its ID, then use that variable to remove a class from the element. For some reason my program seems to crash when I try this. My html snipped looks like this:

```
<td class="square light" id="1"></td>
```

And my javascript using jquery looks like this:

```
var firstTouch = false;
var startID = 0;
$('.square').click(function(){
    if (firstTouch == false){
        startID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(startID);
        firstTouch = true;
    } else {
        var startSquare = document.getElementById(startID);
        startSquare.removeClass('pawnA');
        firstTouch = false;
    }
});
```

I was wondering if anybody has an idea as to why it isn't working. When I alert on the variable startSquare it gives: [object HTMLTableCellElement]
So I'm guessing it found the element, but it doesn't seem to want to remove the class unfortunately.

Comment: It's just `$(this).toggleClass('pawnA')` , the rest of your code is just jumping through hoops for no apparent reason, like getting the ID, and getting the exact same element with that ID etc.

Comment: Try to minimize your problem and supply the complete code to reproduce your problem. See (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Because getting an element via the pure JS doesn't define `startSquare` as a jQuery object; do it with jQuery selectors...

```
$("#"+ startID).removeClass('pawnA');
```